# Grunt Environment Variables Don't Get Set Until All Tasks Loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs, environment-variables

I am using the `npm` modules [grunt env](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-env) and [load-grunt-config](https://www.npmjs.org/package/load-grunt-config) in my project. `grunt env` handles environment variables for you, while `load-grunt-config` handles, well, loads the `grunt` configuration for you. You can put your tasks into other files, then `load-grunt-config` will bundle them up and have `grunt` load & consume them for you. You can also make an `aliases.js` file, with tasks you want to combine together into one task, running one after another. It's similar to the [grunt.registerTask](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task) task in the original `Gruntfile.js`. I put all my `grunt` tasks inside a separate `grunt/` folder under the root folder with the main `Gruntfile`, with no extra subfolders, as suggested by the `load-grunt-config` README.md on Github. Here is my slimmed-down `Gruntfile`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    'use strict';

    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // function & property declarations
    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')

    });

    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        init: true,
        loadGruntConfig: {
            scope: 'devDependencies', 
            pattern: ['grunt-*', 'time-grunt']
        }
    });

};
```

In theory, setting all these files up the correct way for `load-grunt-config` to load should be exactly the same as just having a `Gruntfile.js`. However, I seem to have run into a little snag. It seems the environment variables set under the `env` task do not get set for the subsequent `grunt` tasks, but are set by the time `node` processes its tasks, in this case an `express` server.

`grunt env` task:

```
module.exports = {

    // environment variable values for developers
    // creating/maintaining site
    dev: {
        options: {
            add: {
                NODE_ENV: 'dev',
                MONGO_PORT: 27017,
                SERVER_PORT: 3000
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[grunt-shell-spawn](https://github.com/cri5ti/grunt-shell-spawn) task:

```
// shell command tasks
module.exports = {

    // starts up MongoDB server/daemon
    mongod: {
        command: 'mongod --bind_ip konneka.org --port ' + (process.env.MONGO_PORT || 27017) + ' --dbpath C:/MongoDB/data/db --ipv6',
        options: {
            async: true, // makes this command asynchronous
            stdout: false, // does not print to the console
            stderr: true, // prints errors to the console
            failOnError: true, // fails this task when it encounters errors
            execOptions: {
                cwd: '.'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[grunt express](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express) task:

```
module.exports = {

    // default options
    options: {
        hostname: '127.0.0.1', // allow connections from localhost
        port: (process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000), // default port

    },

    prod: {
        options: {
            livereload: true, // automatically reload server when express pages change
            // serverreload: true, // run forever-running server (do not close when finished)
            server: path.resolve(__dirname, '../backend/page.js'), // express server file
            bases: 'dist/' // watch files in app folder for changes
        }
    }
};
```

`aliases.js` file (`grunt-load-config`'s way of combining tasks so they run one after the other):

```
module.exports = {
    // starts forever-running server with "production" environment
    server: ['env:prod', 'shell:mongod', 'express:prod', 'express-keepalive']
};
```

part of `backend/env/prod.js` (environment-specific Express configuration, loaded if `NODE_ENV` is set to "prod", modeled after [MEAN.JS](https://github.com/meanjs/mean)):

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    port: process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3001,
    dbUrl: process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://konneka.org:' + (process.env.MONGO_PORT || 27018) + '/mean'
};
```

part of `backend/env/dev.js` (environment-specific Express configuration for `dev` environment, loaded if the `NODE_ENV variable is not set or is set to "dev"):

```
module.exports = {
    port: process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000,
    dbUrl: 'mongodb://konneka.org:' + (process.env.MONGO_PORT || 27017) + '/mean-dev'
};
```

part of `backend/page.js` (my Express configuration page, also modeled after MEAN.JS):

```
'use strict';
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var express = require('express');
var server = express();

...

// create the database object
var monServer = mongoose.connect(environ.dbUrl);

// create a client-server session, using a MongoDB collection/table to store its info
server.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: environ.sessionSecret,
    store: new mongoStore({
        db: monServer.connections[0].db, // specify the database these sessions will be saved into
        auto_reconnect: true
    })
}));

...

// listen on port related to environment variable
server.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000);

module.exports = server;
```

When I run `grunt server`, I get:

```
$ cd /c/repos/konneka/ && grunt server
Running "env:prod" (env) task

Running "shell:mongod" (shell) task

Running "express:prod" (express) task

Running "express-server:prod" (express-server) task
Web server started on port:3000, hostname: 127.0.0.1 [pid: 3996]

Running "express-keepalive" task
Fatal error: failed to connect to [konneka.org:27018]


Execution Time (2014-08-15 18:05:31 UTC)
loading tasks        38.3s  █████████████████████████████████ 79%
express-server:prod   8.7s  ████████ 18%
express-keepalive     1.2s  ██ 2%
Total 48.3s
```

Now, I can't seem to get the database connected in the first place, but ignore that for now.  Notice that the server is started on port 3000, meaning that during execution of the `grunt express:prod` task, `SERVER_PORT` is not set so the port gets set to 3000. There are numerous other examples like this, where an environment variable is not set so my app uses the default. However, notice that `session` tries to connect to the database on port 27018 (and fails), so `MONGO_PORT` does get set eventually.

If I had just tried the `grunt server` task, I could chalk it up to `load-grunt-config` running the tasks in parallel instead of one after the other or some other error, but even when I try the tasks one-by-one, such as running `grunt env:prod shell:mongod express-server:prod express-keepalive`, I get similar (incorrect) results, so either `grunt` or `grunt env` run the tasks in parallel, as well, or something else is going on.

What's going on here? Why are the environment variables not set correctly for later `grunt` tasks? When are they eventually set, and why then rather than some other time? How can I make them get set for `grunt` tasks themselves rather than after, assuming there even is a way?

Comment: I'm working up a complete test case for this, but my initial thought is that `grunt env` is only setting the environment variables once grunt has executed all of its tasks. Possible solution is to combine the env task into the other tasks.

Comment: I'm trying to combine the tasks. That's why I'm using `load-grunt-config` and `grunt`'s own methods like `registerTask`. But I know what you mean, and I suppose I'll try that later.

Comment: Could we get the output from `tree` (or some insight into what files and folders are in the picture)?

Comment: I am on Windows with mSysGit. Is there any other way? I put the `grunt` tasks into a separate `grunt/` folder, as suggested by `load-grunt-config`. No subfolders, just the `grunt/` folder.

Comment: @Whymarrh, I just added it to the question. I apologize, I suppose I assumed it wasn't important to the question or that "everyone does it that way". Will I ever learn? I also thought it would add too much to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is rather obvious once you figure it out, so let's start at the beginning:

#### The problem

You're using [`load-grunt-config`](https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config) to load a set of modules (objects that define tasks) and combine them into one module (object) and pass it along to Grunt. To better understand what `load-grunt-config` is doing, take a moment to [read through the source (it's just three files)](https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config/tree/dc1ed3944d6b2334a4276ffaab0ed0041fd29416/lib). So, instead of writing:

```
// filename: Gruntfile.js
grunt.initConfig({
    foo: {
        a: {
            options: {},
        }
    },
    bar: {
        b: {
            options: {},
        }
    }
});
```

You can write this:

```
// filename: grunt/foo.js
module.exports = {
    a: {
        options: {},
    }
}

// filename: grunt/bar.js
module.exports = {
    b: {
        options: {},
    }
}

// filename: Gruntfile.js
require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);
```

Basically, this way you can split up a Grunt configuration into multiple files and have it be more "maintainable". But what you'll need to realize is that these two approaches are semantically equivalent. That is, you can expect them to behave the same way.

Thus, when you write the following*:

(* I've reduced the problem in an attempt to make this answer a bit more general and to reduce noise. I've excluded things like loading the tasks and extraneous option passing, but the error should still be the same. **Also note that I've changed the values of the environment variables** because the default was the same as what was being set.)

```
// filename: grunt/env.js
module.exports = {
    dev: {
        options: {
            add: {
                // These values are different for demo purposes
                NODE_ENV: 'dev',
                MONGO_PORT: 'dev_mongo_port',
                SERVER_PORT: 'dev_server_port'
            }
        }
    }
};

// filename: grunt/shell.js
module.exports = {
    mongod: {
        command: 'mongod --port ' + (process.env.MONGO_PORT || 27017)
    }
};

// filename: grunt/aliases.js
module.exports = {
    server: ['env:prod', 'shell:mongod']
};

// filename: Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);
};
```

You can consider the above the same as below:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        env: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    add: {
                        NODE_ENV: 'dev',
                        MONGO_PORT: 'dev_mongo_port',
                        SERVER_PORT: 'dev_server_port'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        shell: {
            mongod: {
                command: 'mongod --port ' + (process.env.MONGO_PORT || 27017)
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('server', ['env:dev', 'shell:mongod']);
};
```

Now do you see the problem? What command do you expect `shell:mongod` to run? The correct answer is:

```
mongod --port 27017
```

Where what you want to be executed is:

```
mongo --port dev_mongo_port
```

The problem is that when `(process.env.MONGO_PORT || 27017)` is evaluated the environment variables have not yet been set (i.e. before the `env:dev` task has been run).

#### A solution

Well let's look at a working Grunt configuration before splitting it across multiple files:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        env: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    add: {
                        NODE_ENV: 'dev',
                        MONGO_PORT: 'dev_mongo_port',
                        SERVER_PORT: 'dev_server_port'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        shell: {
            mongod: {
                command: 'mongod --port ${MONGO_PORT:-27017}'
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('server', ['env:dev', 'shell:mongod']);
};
```

Now when you run `shell:mongod`, the command will contain `${MONGO_PORT:-27017}` and Bash (or just sh) will look for the environment variable you would have set in the task before it (i.e. `env:dev`).

Okay, that's all well and good for the `shell:mongod` task, but what about the other tasks, Express for example?

You'll need to move away from environment variables (unless you want to set them up *before* invoking Grunt. Why? Take this Grunt configuration for example:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        env: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    add: {
                        NODE_ENV: 'dev',
                        MONGO_PORT: 'dev_mongo_port',
                        SERVER_PORT: 'dev_server_port'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        express: {
            options: {
                hostname: '127.0.0.1'
                port: (process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000)
            },
            prod: {
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                    server: path.resolve(__dirname, '../backend/page.js'),
                    bases: 'dist/'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('server', ['env:dev', 'express:prod']);
};
```

What port will the `express:prod` task configuration contain? `3000`. What you need is for it to reference the value you've defined in the above task. How you do this is up to you. You could:

- Separate the `env` configuration and reference its values

  ```
  module.exports = function (grunt) {
      grunt.config('env', {
          dev: {
              options: {
                  add: {
                      NODE_ENV: 'dev',
                      MONGO_PORT: 'dev_mongo_port',
                      SERVER_PORT: 'dev_server_port'
                  }
              }
          }
      });
      grunt.config('express', {
          options: {
              hostname: '127.0.0.1'
              port: '<%= env.dev.options.add.SERVER_PORT %>'
          }
      });
      grunt.registerTask('server', ['env:dev', 'express:prod']);
  };
  ```

  But you'll notice that the semantics of the `env` task don't hold up here due to it no longer representing a task's configuration. You could use an object of your own design:

  ```
  module.exports = function (grunt) {
      grunt.config('env', {
          dev: {
              NODE_ENV: 'dev',
              MONGO_PORT: 'dev_mongo_port',
              SERVER_PORT: 'dev_server_port'
          }
      });
      grunt.config('express', {
          options: {
              hostname: '127.0.0.1'
              port: '<%= env.dev.SERVER_PORT %>'
          }
      });
      grunt.registerTask('server', ['env:dev', 'express:prod']);
  };
  ```
- Pass `grunt` an argument to specify what config it should use
- Have multiple configuration files (e.g. `Gruntfile.js.dev` and `Gruntfile.js.prod`) and rename them as needed
- Read a development configuration file (e.g. `grunt.file.readJSON('config.development.json')`) if it exists and fall back to a production configuration file if it doesn't exist
- **Some better way not listed here**

But all of the above should achieve the same end result.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! You definitely deserve the bounty. I can't believe I didn't think to test this configuration on a plain old `Gruntfile` first, it would have saved months of trouble. D'oh! I think I may go with your "configuration file" approach. It's pretty much what I'm doing already, with the `grunt/env.js` file, but now I'll have more than one.

Comment: So you are saying `grunt` evaluates variables before any tasks are run? That seems rather silly, considering how many times you can think of where you would want `grunt` to evaluate variables *during* a task, like this question.

Comment: Grunt doesn't evaluate the variables, Node (or JavaScript) does (kind of, I don't know how best to explain this). It comes down to where the variable is used -- if the variable is used inside a task then it is evaluated when the task is run. If the variable is used when defining a task then it is evaluated when the task is defined. The `grunt env` task is useful if what you want to use environment variables.

Comment: So in this case the variable is used when defining the task, not when using it? Interesting... I think I have an idea about how I will solve my problem, using your "custom object" idea. I will add it to my question when I get a chance.

Comment: @trysis If you have a new question, feel free to ask it as a new question. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I am thinking about it. My questions in these comments are rhetorical or ask for clarification on your question, however. If I have an actual question, I will ask it as a new question.

Comment: Your `grunt shell` suggestion doesn't work on mSysGit in `grunt`. It works outside of `grunt`, so `grunt` must get a new environment or something outside of `sh.exe`.

Comment: @trysis [Your problem is this.](https://github.com/cri5ti/grunt-shell-spawn/blob/c0625a975bb53298ec01d4c921470cd6f33cc853/tasks/shell.js#L52-L59) I'm not sure what can be done about it really, other than submitting a PR with a flag to force the command or using one of the alternatives I proposed. Grunt itself isn't doing anything fancy with environments.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the essence of what you are trying to do, and it works for me. The important part was what I mentioned in my comment -- chaining the environment task before running the other tasks.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Do grunt-related things in here
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');

  grunt.initConfig({
      env: {
          dev: {
              PROD : 'http://production.server'
           }
      }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('printEnv', 'prints a message with an env var', function() { console.log('Env var in subsequent grunt task: ' + process.env.PROD) } );

  grunt.registerTask('prod', ['env:dev', 'printEnv']);

};
```

**Output of `grunt prod`**

```
Running "env:dev" (env) task

Running "printEnv" task
Env var in subsequent grunt task: http://production.server

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: So you are saying to not use `load-grunt-config` for the environment setting, but instead the regular `grunt.registerTask`?

Comment: Because this should be exactly the same as what `load-grunt-config` is doing. You're no more "combining" or "chaining" the `env` task with the other tasks than I was.

Comment: @trysis I'm not sure what load-grunt-config is doing, but I thought this would help you do what you were trying to do. I'll see if I can make it work with load-grunt-config.

Comment: Because I told you it wasn't helping & you weren't responding or editing. I may have acted a little prematurely, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, @ctlacko, I can't undo my downvote until you edit the question. Sorry again.

Comment: No worries. It may take some time before I can edit it to work with load-grunt-config, so perhaps the downvote will encourage others to jump in from a different angle.

Comment: I'm glad you're so understanding. I didn't want to say anything before because I figured I had already said enough (2 comments on both question & answer, only 1 other comment). Maybe I should have, though.

Comment: @ctlacko This is not the essence of the problem. This example is actually fundamentally different from the problem as the usage of `process.env.*` is _inside_ the task.